# How can I use a for loop inside of a print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I want to use a for loop inside of a printed statement, basically the user inputs the word, and it prints that out after a variable. Something like this

If they input the word "Pizza" it will output:

```
I like P
I like i
I like z
I like z
I like a
```

PIZZA
Exactly like that.

I've already tried a slow way, using print(name[0]) and print(name[1]) and so on but I realized there would be errors if the inputted text wasn't exactly 5 characters.

Comment: Hey OpBanana, Look for List comprehensions in Python

Comment: `print(' '.join('I like %s' % i for i in 'Pizza'))`?

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that in order to keep SO full of amazing answers to interesting problems, some other problems, like homework, get downvoted, closed and removed.

Comment: Asking homework questions [should be OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2745495) as long as the OP made some attempt at researching and solving the problem on their own, and they asked a specific problem or a specific portion of the code, rather than asking how to do the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
texts = ["PIZZA", "RED WINE"]
for i in range(len(texts)):
    text = "".join(texts[i].split())
    print(' '.join('I like %s' % i for i in text))
```

In case you need another word except the PIZZA.

Comment: No need for 2 list comprehensions. Loop over each word (`for txt in texts`) and then  loop over each character of the word (`print(' '.join('I like %s' % c for c in txt))`)

Comment: My mistake. I think it should add the "PIZZA" along with the word.